# How to get last element of an array in scala

Tags: scala

How to get the last element from array if present. In below code num contains array of elements

```
 var line_ = ln.trim 
 if(!line_.isEmpty) {
     var num = line_.split(" ");
 }
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just use `last`:

```
 var num = line_.split(" ").last;
```

Comment: How about `val num = ln.trim.split(" ").last`. Do you really like to read few lines instead of one?

Comment: @pawel.panasewicz: like Mark said, that will not work if the line is empty. Good thing the isEmpty check was already there...

Answer (score 15):

Last will work if the Array is not empty.  You might prefer lastOption:

```
scala> Array.empty[String].lastOption
 res5: Option[String] = None

 scala> "ab".toArray.lastOption
 res6: Option[Char] = Some(b)
```